# Vuex mutation running but the state is not being updated

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am using vuex store for state management. Basically I want to set a global app loading state for all requests and use axios interceptors to set the loading state instead of doing this manually for each request.

I have my store as shown below: **NOTICE THE CONSOLE LOGS**

```
export default store(function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = createStore({
    state() {
      return {
        appLoading: false
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      toggleAppLoader(state, payload) {
        console.log('setting state to ', payload, ' from ', state.appLoading)
        state.appLoading = payload
      }
    },

    // enable strict mode (adds overhead!)
    // for dev mode and --debug builds only
    strict: process.env.DEBUGGING
  })

  return Store
})
```

Now in my axios boot.js file in the interceptors, I have this:

```
import store from '../store/index'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  api.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
      // Do something before request is sent
      store().commit('toggleAppLoader', true)
      console.log('State set to true: ', store().state.appLoading)
      return config
    },
  )
});
```

See attached screenshot of the console logs

[image]

You will notice that when I fetch the state immediately, the value is not updating as stated.

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools?

Comment: Nothing is changing in the vue devtools. Still has the intial state

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it seems that every time you call `store()`, a new store instance is created.

Try changing your function to

```
const localStore = store();

localStore.commit('toggleAppLoader', true)
console.log('State set to true: ', localStore.state.appLoading)

return config
```

If my guess is correct then it's fixed this way, but in other contexts (components or basically everywhere else) you will be still instantiating new stores. You'll probably need to make a global instance.

What you have in your store file [is actually a factory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_(object-oriented_programming)). To make it work as a global instance, just use:

```
const globalStore = createStore(........);
export default globalStore;
```

And import it elsewhere afterwards;

```
import globalStore from 'yourfile';
```

And use it calling f.e. `globalStore.state.appLoading`

Comment: To some degree this worked, because after defining this at the start `const storeInst = store()` and using that, the states are updated accordingly but now it looks like the instance I am updating and the global instance are different. I want to update the global instance

Comment: That's precisely what I meant by other contexts. This is a separate question actually, but we'll, anyways. I'll update the answer.